# PHP ftp_nlist unexpected behaviour

Tags: php, ftp

FTP function fpt_nlist() always returns 2 additional elements: '/.' and '/..', so even if I use it on empty directory, I never get an empty array.

Is this normal? Can i get rid of this problem or must accept as it is?

If i check whether folder is empty or not, this way it always says that folder isn't empty.

Of course i can overcome this with:

```
if ($list !== FALSE AND count($list) > 0)
{
    foreach ($list as $item)
    {
        if ($item != $filepath.'.' AND $item != $filepath.'..')
        {
        }
    }
}
```

but I'd like to solve this problem instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* the expected behavior since `.` and `..` are special files (directory symbols).

`.` relates to the current directory and `..` relates to the parent directory (except for in the root directory, where it also represents itself)

This schema is used in any OS I worked with (UNIX, Linux, OSx, Windows) and you should expect `fpt_nlist()` to return them.

Comment: I knew what they are but thanks for reminding. Actually, above code is part of Codeigniter library and it checks whether folder is empty or not. In original it doesn't include last internal instruction _if_ and it cause endless loop. I 'fixed' it because i didn't expect that their library has faults.